# React to events from a collection within a model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

```
SubCollection extends Backbone.Collection

Model extends Backbone.Model
   subcollection: new SubCollection()

model1 = new Model

model2 = new Model
```

When the collection in `model1` changes I need to update the collection in `model2`. They cant be a reference to the same collection, when one changes I need to react to the change and apply it to the collection in the other model.

How would I do this? Is this hard to do?

Thanks!

Comment: i'd like to know this as well. is there some standard way or accepted convention to bubble various events up through the hierarchy and listen for/catch them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well,

we can't really be sure that there is only the model1 and model2, we could have a model3 and model4, so we cannot actually go binding manually to the models, otherwise you would get a big mess like this:

```
// not an option... >> huge mess :)
model1.bind('add', myFunction());
model2.bind('add', myFunction());
model3.bind('add', myFunction());
```

**so, what we can do instead**

would be to implement an event aggregator in our application. and work with custom events instead.

```
// application object
var app = {
    evt: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
};

// subcollection
var SubCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){

        _.bindAll(this, "bubbleEvent", "catchBubbledEvent");

        this.bind('reset', this.myBubble);
        this.bind('add', this.myBubble);
        this.bind('reset', this.myBubble);
        //... every event you want to catch

        app.evt.bind('myCustomEvent', this.catchBubbledEvent);
    },

    bubbleEvent: function(x, y){
        // triggering a general event, passing the parameters
        app.evt.trigger('myCustomEvent', x, y, this);
    },

    catchBubbledEvent: function(x, y, originalCollection) {
        // catch any event raised on the event aggregator and cancel out the loop (don't catch events raised by this very own collection :)
        if(originalCollection.id === this.id)
            return;

       // do your stuff here ...
    }
});

//model
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // notice me setting a unique ID in the collection, i pass in the client id of this instance of the model
    subCollection: new SubCollection({id: this.cid});
});
```

so basically we catch every event of the collection we want to, then we pass it trough to a general event on the single event Aggregator we have for our whole app, anything can bind to that, and do stuff when the proper event is raised, so can our collection bind to it, and do stuff. since this is possible that your collection catches the event that it sent out himself, we need a small test to cancel out these situations... and only continue when another collection raised this event.